# Include an app only in certain builds in AOSP by changing .bp file

Tags: android-source, android-soong

Is there a way to change a .bp file of an app in AOSP so that is only included in a certain build.

For example I want to include test apps only in userdebug apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way to do it is not changing the Android.bp file, but change the device//.mk file to include the tests apps only in userdebug builds like this:

```
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += main_app_1

ifneq (,$(filter userdebug eng, $(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)))
PRODUCT_PACKAGES += test_main_app_1
endif
```

In Android.bp, you should build the main app and the test app separately, like this:

```
cc_binary {
    name: "main_app_1",
    cflags: [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-ffunction-sections",
        "-fPIC",
        "-Werror",
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-O2",
    ],
    srcs: [
        "src/**/*.cc",
    ],
    shared_libs: [
        "liblog",
        "libcutils",
        "libandroid_runtime",
        "libutils",
    ],
}

cc_binary {
    name: "test_main_app_1",
    cflags: [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-ffunction-sections",
        "-fPIC",
        "-Werror",
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-O2",
    ],
    srcs: [
        "test/**/*.cc",
    ],
    local_include_dirs: ["test/"],
    shared_libs: [
        "liblog",
        "libcutils",
        "libandroid_runtime",
        "libutils",
    ],
}
```

Comment: So there isn't a way to do what I'm asking for?